# how to find external sdcard(mnt/exdsdcard) path android?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

## Exdsdcard path find

> i need to find out external sdcard path(mnt/exdsdcard).i want to same some images to exdsdcard and i went access database also.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: @songyy:thanks for reply.. i try this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Then specify the foldername and file name

for e.g:

"/LazyList/"+serialno.get(position).trim()+".jpg"