# Cannot write to Sdcard in Android ChromeTestShell

Tags: android, file-io, sd-card

I have build the Android Chrome test shell (v27.0.1453.49) using instructions from the website.
I need to dump some data to a file in SDCARD from chrome code, but hit the errno=13 everytime. I already tried using all paths /mnt/sdcard/, /sdcard, /storage/XX

My manifest contains the below already.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My target device is JellyBean 4.1.2.

Any advice?

Comment: if you had used emulator, had you set the sdcard size while creating.

Comment: I tried it on a device directly. Haven't used the emulator. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: Did you try to get SD Card something like this...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765441/how-to-find-external-sdcardmnt-exdsdcard-path-android

Comment: this one also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location

Comment: I looked at them before posting this, but both of them are for the SDK. I wanted to dump to file form native code in Chrome. Specifically I was trying to dump the SKbitmap to file for reference.

Comment: BTW as per the post , the contents of my /system/etc/vold.conf say the mount point as /sdcard. There is a ums_path as well which is different. Do you reckon I use that?

Comment: Sory dn't have much idea, Just new to Android. But you can write a dummy program which simply write on your device's sdcard. To access a file directly, "file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/sleepaway.mp3", I used something like this. Just try it once. Yeah, one more thing, don't forget to parse "file path string" to URI. It worked for me perfectly. All the best !!!

Comment: @surender8388 - The normal application has worked for me as well. But I think there is something peculiar about the Chrome test shell, that is preventing me from writing to disk. 2 process maybe? :(

Comment: Any more suggestions? This is still not working for me.